# Is it possible to test the app in Google Play both internal test and closed test with the same account

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I wonder is it possible to test both internal test version and closed test version using the same device and same account. May be something like select version when install the app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a user/device always receives **the highest versionCode** it is eligible to receive.

To switch between tracks, you have to uninstall the app (only if you want to downgrade to a lower versionCode), change which track you have access to, wait a bit for the propagation, then re-install the app (or update if the versionCode is higher).